# Azure CLI query help - JMESPath - filter using key having space , extract keys with space in them ( from Powershell )

Tags: azure, powershell, tags, azure-cli, jmespath

Good morning everyone, **Happy Friday**!
**Edit**: Ended up solving it myself while debugging through it..
Thought I will post it here regardless so that anyone who comes here may get the solution...
Was helped by microsoft docs.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively
```

### Original question

I have Azure Resources which are tagged like :

```
"tags":{
"Application Name":"The Best App",
"Budget Line":"Home project",
"Technology":"Best Tech",
"Environment":"Development",
"Project":"Learn"
}
```

Sample json with array of resources and tags would look like

```
[{"name":"Resource1",
"tags": {
"Application Name":"The Best App",
"Budget Line":"Home project",
"Technology":"Best Tech",
"Environment":"Development",
"Project":"Learn"
 }},
{"name":"Resource2",
"tags": {
"Application Name":"The Best App",
"Budget Line":"Home project",
"Technology":"Best Tech",
"Environment":"Development",
"Project":"Learn"
 }},
{"name":"Resource3",
"tags": {
"Application Name":"Not App",
"Budget Line":"Home project",
"Technology":"Best Tech",
"Environment":"Development",
"Project":"Learn"
 }
}
]
```

So now I am looking to query all Azure Resources where the tag `**Application Name** = **The Best App**.`

I was going through the JMESPath tutorial and got the following syntax to work on the JMESPath tutorial website.
What I tried to do :
Filter a resource based on a tag value, and then extract another tag value of those resources.

```
[?tags."Application Name"==`"The Best App"`].tags."Budget Line"
```

[image: JMES Path filter with space in key name and space in key name while projecting]

Next step was to try the same query as part of an azure cli query with JMESPath filter query.
Note I am running azure cli from **PowerShell** as I am more comfortable in it than Bash.
Unable to get it to work

### Solution after quite a few trial and error

Looking at the powershell examples for escaping double quotes from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively
These worked : Examples are in **PowerShell**

- Query an azure resource based on a tag key which does not have space in it, but project/extract the value of a tag having key name with space.

  ```
  az resource list -g RESOURCEGROUPNAME --query "[?tags.Technology==`'Best Tech'`].tags.\`"Budget Line\`"" # Works in powershell
  ```
- Query an azure resource based on a tag key which **has** a space in it, and extract/project the value of a tag having key name with space.

  ```
  az resource list -g RESOURCEGROUPNAME --query "[?tags.\`"Budget Line\`"==`'Home Project'`].tags.\`"Application Name\`"" # Works in powershell
  ```

Happy Friday guys! Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution after quite a few trial and error

Looking at the powershell examples for escaping double quotes from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively
These worked : Examples are in **PowerShell**

- Query an azure resource based on a tag key which does not have space in it, but project/extract the value of a tag having key name with space.

  ```
  az resource list -g RESOURCEGROUPNAME --query "[?tags.Technology==`'Best Tech'`].tags.\`"Budget Line\`"" # Works in powershell
  ```
- Query an azure resource based on a tag key which **has** a space in it, and extract/project the value of a tag having key name with space.

  ```
  az resource list -g RESOURCEGROUPNAME --query "[?tags.\`"Budget Line\`"==`'Home Project'`].tags.\`"Application Name\`"" # Works in powershell
  ```

Happy Friday guys! Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

This is a totally different context, but just in case it helps somebody, the author's solution didn't work for me [doing a JSON query from Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries) (which also uses JMESPath).  Instead, I had to do the following:

```yaml
storage_url: "{{ openstack_api_versions.stdout | from_json | json_query('[? \"Service Type\" == `object-store`].Endpoint') | first }}"
```

In this context, it only works without backticks.